# how are connections between artificial neurons modified during training?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

## background

In Tesla Autonomy Day, Andrej Karpathy gave a presentation. In this presentation he said, among other things, that in the beginning the connections between artificial neurons in an artificial neural network are randomly initialized. Therefore, the network makes random predictions.

Later he said that information flows forward through the network and then, via the back-propagation algorithm, the information flows backwards through the network. When information flows backward the connections between neurons are modified. In turn, the network makes better and better predictions.

Moreover, I also learnt from some lectures online that the connections(weights) between neurons are stored in matrices.

## question

So my question is what is the mathematical formula or equation connecting these two facts?

That is, how are these matrices modified via the back-propagation algorithm?

Comment: Back-propagation and the internal mechanics of network topologies are covered on many sites and in many on-line presentations.  Can you perhaps check with a couple of those, and explain where you're not clear on the mechanics?

Answer (score 4):

This is a good question.

Say you have a simple neural network with a single hidden layer

```
a1 = g(x W1)
a2 = g(a1 W2)
y = g(a2)
```

Where `a1` is the activation, or output, of the first layer, `a2` is the activation of the hidden layer, and `y` is the output. `W1,W2` are the weight matrices. `g()` is some non-linear 'activation function' which is used to make the neural network encode more complex relations. Also note that in order to introduce a bias element (`b` from linear regression), by convention we make the first element of `a` equal to `1`: `ak[0]=1`.

Now computing `y` is what we call 'forward flow', or 'forward propagation'. Notice that in order to compute `y` you only need the input data `x`. This is also called inference.

However, in order for the network to make competent predictions, we have to update the weight matrices. There are multiple different ways of updating the network, but gradient descent is a common method.

In order to use gradient descent, we need some sort of metric of how good the network is doing, or more precisely how bad it's doing. We define a function called the error function that depends on the output of the network, as well as the real answer.

```
def error(y, y'):
   # approximately MSE. 
   return sum((y-y').^2)
```

Now in order to update the weights, we want to figure out how much each weight contributed to the error score, and update it in a way makes the contribution smaller. This is where gradient descent comes in

```
W -= alpha * diff(error(y,y'), W)
```

Where `alpha` is some small positive real value, and `diff(f,x)` is the derivative of `f` with respect to `x`, or in this case, the error with respect to the weight matrix.

But how do we compute the derivative? This is where backpropagation comes in. Instead of analytically finding the derivatives, software packages such as Tensorflow and Pytorch uses something called auto-differentiation to automate the process.

The idea is to recursively apply the chain rule until you break down the complex error function into a sum of atomic functions for which you have manually computed the derivative. Since this starts at the last layer and flows backwards through the network, it's called backpropagation even though I think it's a bit misleading.

Recall that the chain rule is

```
(f(g(x)))' = f'(g(x)) g'(x)
```

Once you've broken the composite function `f(g(x))` down, you can apply the chain rule again if you don't know how to compute the derivative of either `f` or `g`.

---

So in summary, you asked

1. So my question is what is the mathematical formula or equation connecting these two facts?

The information 'flows forwards' (forward propagation) during inference, as you start with the input at the first layer and end up with the output at the last layer.

The information 'flows backwards' when decomposing the derivative starting at the last layer moving backwards through the network towards the first layer.

2. That is, how are these matrices modified via the back-propagation algorithm?

The matrices are modified using an algorithm called gradient descent which tries to iteratively make the weight matrices a little better with respect to some error function. In order to do so, it needs the gradient of the error function, and for that we use auto differentiation in which we recursively break down the derivative starting at the last layer moving backwards through towards the first layer hence the name backpropagation.